# Iterate shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Let's assume I have the following:

```
auto vec = std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>
```

And I want to loop through all the `vec` entities using `C++11` Range-Based for Loop.

The following works:

```
for (auto entity: *vec)
```

my question is there anyway to do the same without using the `*` operator?

Comment: Why would you want to omit the `*`?

Comment: The name is shared pointer, hence no.

Comment: I can understand a vector containing shared pointers, but not a shared pointer containing a vector.

Comment: I tried to simplify my problem here. We are facing a very complex data structures in our code (`shared_ptr<vec<shared_ptr<something>>>` and even worse) and I'm wondering if I can make the code more readable by avoiding any unnecessary operator and parentheses. omitting `*` would help in this way, nothing more.

Comment: You can improve readability by for example `using something_vec = shared_ptr<vec<shared_ptr<something>>>`, or `using something_ptr = shared_ptr<something>` and `using something_vec = shared_ptr<something_vec>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. The only sensible way to dereference a pointer is with the dereference operator.

Comment: I love short answers. Thank you :)